# Help on identifying a sharp leaved white-(another variety of it is red-)flowered perennial

Tags: identification, perennials

In my garden I have a perennial (at least in a second year) in two varieties (one white-flowered, one red) of the scrub pictured below. I collected seed from it last year and I got seedlings from it this year (seedlings are not pictured).

The leaves are sharp and wound around the stem. The flowers are coming out of the stem as well. It flowers in July and August.

The red variety (not pictured) is a little bit weaker than the white one - it is smaller and flowers less and later.

The scrub I have consists of several stems which have been cut down last autumn and now they are back like if nothing has happened.

The white variety is about 1.20m high; the red one 0.80-1m.

Thanks for giving me a hint on its ID.

*click to enlarge the images*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [Gaura lindheimeri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaura_lindheimeri).  The white cultivar is probably "Whirling Butterflies" and the one with the darker red flowers is likely to be "Siskiyou Pink".  I have grown them both.  They tolerate heat and drought but will not take poor drainage in the winter.  If you have clay based soils a raised bed with a freer draining soil will help.

Comment: Thanks for this super fast answer. Of course you're right. I will update my question with a picture from the red version and confirm whether it is Siskiyou Pink or not once they are flowering.